# Spring batch, logging Skipped records / lines

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

In order to be able to log all skipped record / lines (from Flat file), I have linked Item (Data model) to `FieldSet.getValues()` in `FieldSetMapper<T>` implementation.

Here `record` is my Data model.

```
public void loadRecord(FieldSet fieldSet){
    record.setFieldSet(fieldSet.getValues());
}
```

SB provides record/line for `onSkipInRead` in the `FlatFileParseException`. To have the same for `onSkipInWrite` and `onSkipInProcess`, I came up with the above solution.
Also, `record` does  not store all the fields from the flat file, hence I can't each line using just the Data model.

1. Is this a good way to acheive this ?
2. Are there any other ways to do this ?
3. Is the record / line corresponding to an Item stored in any context ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: 1. no, really bad solution
2. read documentation about [`FieldSetMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/FieldSetMapper.html) and download SB start guide example; all will be more clear!

Comment: I tried looking at these links https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ , https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-batch-processing/ , but didnt find anything useful

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci my Item does not store all fields from the flat file, so I cant regenerate the flat file line from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understand better your problem :) 
Save the whole line into your domain object and not the `FieldSet` using a custom `LineMapper`.
From `LineMapper` javadoc:

> Interface for mapping lines (strings) to domain objects typically used
>   to map lines read from a file to domain objects on a per line basis.
>   Implementations of this interface perform the actual work of parsing a
>   line without having to deal with how the line was obtained.

So with a delegate is pretty easy solve your problem:

```
class StoreLineLineMapper implements LineMapper<DomainObject> {
  private LineMapper<DomainObject> delegate;

  public DomainObject mapLine(java.lang.String line, int lineNumber) throws java.lang.Exception {
    DomainObject record = delegate.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
    record.setLineInfo(new LineInfo(line, lineNumber));
    return record;
  }
}
```

Comment: I also need to populate some other fields of `record` with values from tokens of the parsed line. Hence, I prefer my solution over this(really Im not being baised here).

Comment: With my solution you create and populate all fields you want using delegated lineMapper stored in StoreLineLineMapper.delegate property; custom LineMapper is only used to store line info

Answer (score 0):

The complete code for this use case:

```
public class UserMapper implements FieldSetMapper<User> {
    @Override
    public User mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
      User user = new User();
      String ped = fieldSet.readString("Position effective date");
      user.setId(fieldSet.readInt("User ID"));
      user.setFn(fieldSet.readString("First Name"));

      user.loadRecord(fieldSet); // store fieldSet for regenerating line in future
    return user;
  }
}
```

This will regenerate line from fieldSet (Delimiter is TAB):

```
class User{

 @Override
   public String toString() {
     return StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(fieldSet,
            DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB);
 }
}
```

Log lines in SkipListener like this:

```
class SkipListener {

  public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkipListener.class);

  @OnSkipInWrite
  public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable t) {
    onSkip(item);
  }

  @OnSkipInRead
  public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
     FlatFileParseException ffpe = (FlatFileParseException) t;
     onSkip(ffpe.getInput());
    }
  }

  @OnSkipInProcess
  public void onSkipInProcess(Object item, Throwable t) {
    onSkip(item);
  }

  public void onSkip(Object item) {
    logger.info(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: this works,of course. But you tied your domain object with SB classes and this is evil ;) your request is to save lineinfo,not SB object. If you absolutely want store FieldSet object into domain create a new class UserWithFieldSet containing one `User` and one `FieldSet` object and unwrap during process phase

Comment: Im not storing `FieldSet` objects, `loadRecord()` does a `fieldSet.getValues`() and stores the `String[]` returned.